# Making a template work with both std::map and std::unordered_map

Tags: c++

I have the following template function that returns a copy of the given map with swapped keys and values:

```
template<typename M>
auto swapKeysAndValues(const M& m) {
    std::map<typename M::mapped_type, typename M::key_type> swapped;
    for (auto& p : m) {
        swapped.emplace(p.second, p.first);
    }
    return swapped;
}
```

Is there a way of making the above template work for both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`? That is, for `std::map<K, V>`, it should return `std::map<V, K>`, and for `std::unordered_map<K, V>`, it should return `std::unordered_map<V, K>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename V>
auto swapKeyValues(const Map<K, V>& map)
{
    Map<V, K> result;
    for (const auto& p : map) result.emplace(p.second, p.first);
    return result;
}
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/p0DEIBb7fmdKDrBk)

Comment: a good start, but what about allocators, hash functions and comparison predicates?

Comment: @RichardHodges works only with maps with standard predicate/hash/allocator... It's hard to tell which comparator was used etc.

Comment: agree. I think the complexity involved in a correct solution makes the solution more complex than the problem. it's probably not a function that should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of answers here so I'm not going to cover old ground.

There is however an aspect of this that you ought to consider carefully.

unordered maps are not the same as maps - they have the requirement that a hash function exists for the key (in addition to the equality predicate). As we have seen, it's trivial to write a template function that assumes the defaults, but is that what you want?

If both your K and V have hash functions available, then they are already keys. In that case, isn't what you really wanted a `boost::bimap` or `boost::multi_index_map`?